# How do I update a particular item in useState Array in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, web, next.js

So, I have a `useState` that contains data like this:

```
const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState({
   demoData1: '',
    demoData2: '',
    demoData3: '',
    demoArrayData: [{itemName: '', itemNumber: ''}]
 });
```

I have an `onClick` function that I would like to use to update the `demoArrayData`. However, I want to check if the item I want to add into the `demoArrayData` already exist, if it already there in the array, update it with the latest information and return both the updated item and other items there.
If the item is not on the array, add it to the array and return both the newly added item and other items there before. I have this `onClick` function:

```
const handlePackageSizeSelection = (selectedItem: number, itemIndex: number, selectedItemName: string, selectedItemPrice: string )=>{
  

    const orderedListInfo: orderedItemListAttributes = {
        orderedItemName: selectedItemName,
        orderedQuantity: selectedItem?.toString(),
        orderItemPrice: selectedItemPrice,
        orderItemSelectedIndex: itemIndex?.toString()
    }
     setOrderData({...orderData, demoArrayData:[...orderData?.orderedItemList as [], orderedListInfo]})
    setOrderPackageArrayData(updatedArray);       
   
};
```

While this works, it will add same item more than once. Is there a way to make it detect an item that is already in the array, update it and return everything from the state or add the item to the array if not on the array list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some` to check for a matching name before deciding how to update.

```js
const orderedListInfo = {
    itemName: selectedItemName,
    orderedQuantity: selectedItem?.toString(),
    orderItemPrice: selectedItemPrice,
    orderItemSelectedIndex: itemIndex?.toString()
};
setOrderData({
    ...orderData,
    demoArrayData: orderData.demoArrayData.some(o => o.itemName === orderedListInfo.itemName) ?
        orderData.demoArrayData.map(o => o.itemName === orderedListInfo.itemName ? orderedListInfo : o) :
        [...orderData.demoArrayData, orderedListInfo]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this syntax

```
const handlePackageSizeSelection = (selectedItem: number, itemIndex: number, selectedItemName: string, selectedItemPrice: string )=>{
  

    const orderedListInfo: orderedItemListAttributes = {
        orderedItemName: selectedItemName,
        orderedQuantity: selectedItem?.toString(),
        orderItemPrice: selectedItemPrice,
        orderItemSelectedIndex: itemIndex?.toString()
    }
     setOrderData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      demoArrayData: [...prevState.list, orderedListInfo],
    }))
    setOrderPackageArrayData(updatedArray);       
   
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then we can divide the task into steps, that will help you write a readable and clean code also:

```
const handlePackageSizeSelection = (selectedItem: number, itemIndex: number, selectedItemName: string, selectedItemPrice: string ) => {
 const newOrderItemToBeAdded: orderedItemListAttributes = {
  orderedItemName: selectedItemName,
  orderedQuantity: selectedItem?.toString(),
  orderItemPrice: selectedItemPrice,
  orderItemSelectedIndex: itemIndex?.toString()
}

// Check if the item to be add is already there in the demoArrayData
const existingDemoArrayData = [...orderData.demoArrayData];

// You can create a separate util function for this
const alreadyPresentItemIndex = existingDemoArrayData.findIndex(demoItem => demoItem.name === newOrderItemToBeAdded.name);

if (alreadyPresentItemIndex >= 0) {
  // Remove the existing item and insert the new one
  existingDemoArrayData.splice(alreadyPresentItemIndex, 1, newOrderItemToBeAdded);
} else {
  // If it is not there already
  existingDemoArrayData.push(newOrderItemToBeAdded);
}

setOrderData({...orderData, demoArrayData: [...existingDemoArrayData]});

return existingDemoArrayData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use function to update state based on previous state and you should check if updating item exists in previous state or not.

try to update orderDataState this way:

```
setOrderData(prevState => {
    if (prevState.demoArrayData.find(item => item.itemName === selectedItemName)){
        const otherItems = prevState.demoArrayData.filter(item => item.itemName === selectedItemName);
        return({...prevState, demoArrayData:[...otherItems , orderedListInfo]}) 

    }else{
        return({...prevState, demoArrayData:[...prevState?.orderedItemList , orderedListInfo]}) 
    }                
});
```